# Materialize não está responsivo

Tags: html, css, materialize, layout-responsivo

Desenvolvi um site utilizando o css do http://materializecss.com/, porém ele não fica responsivo, gostaria de saber se o materialize é responsivo e se tem que fazer alguma coisa para ele ficar responsivo

Answer (score 2):

Além de estar utilizando as classes de coluna pré definidas certifique-se de estar utilizando a view-port corretamente. Caso tenha dúvida da última etapa acrescente a seguinte linha à seu cabeçalho.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Se já possuir essa linha em seu cabeçalho veja se está utilizando as colunas do materialize corretamente. Na [documentação oficial](http://materializecss.com/grid.html) está bem explicado o funcionamento das mesmas.

Comment: Meu código ja está com essa linha.